# fillna with increasing values for each time slot in pandas

Tags: pandas, sum, diff, rolling-computation

gurus of pandas, here is my dataframe:

```
datetime    c1
jan 1, 12am 10.0
jan 1, 01am NaN
jan 1, 02am NaN
jan 1, 03am NaN
jan 1, 04am 50.0
```

i want to fillna of column c1 by adding mean hourly difference so that the final dataframe looks like this:

```
datetime    c1
jan 1, 12am 10.0
jan 1, 01am 20.0
jan 1, 02am 30.0
jan 1, 03am 40.0
jan 1, 04am 50.0
```

thanks in advance

Comment: How does the mean is computed ? On the whole dataset are from the bounds cells of NaN values ?

Comment: You can use [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html).

Comment: just to clarify the dataframe is indexed on datetime

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.interpolate(inplace=True)`.

The update is in-place, so to see the result print the *df*.

Additional remark: If you want to have *datetime* column in *datetime*
format (instead of *string*), run:

```
df.datetime = pd.to_datetime('2020 ' + df.datetime, format='%Y %b %d, %I%p')
```

Note the year part (*2020*) and a space added, since your input data doesn't
contain it.